# Who was the KALARATRI that was mentioned in Sundara Kanda?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, hanuman

While declaring that he was a messenger of Sri Rama, Sri Hanuma admonishes Ravana, who practiced severe austerities and got so many boons, and yet abducted Sita.

> लक्षिता इयम् मया सीता तथा शोक परायणा |
>   गृह्य याम् न अभिजानासि पन्च आस्याम् इव पन्नगीम् || ५-५१-२३
>
> "Capturing Seetha, whom you do not recognize as a five-hooded female serpent in your abode, has been found by me in that manner, and wholly given over to sorrow."
>
> तपः सम्ताप लब्धः ते यो अयम् धर्म परिग्रहः |
>   न स नाशयितुम् न्याय्य आत्म प्राण परिग्रहः || ५-५१-२५
>
> "It is not proper for you to lose your exceptional longevity and that fortune which is an outcome of your virtue, both of which have been acquired by you through the practice of austerities."
>
> याम् सीता इति अभिजानासि या इयम् तिष्ठति ते वशे || ५-५१-३४
>   काल रात्री इति ताम् विद्धि सर्व लन्का विनाशिनीम् |
>
> "Know her, whom you recognize as Seetha and who stays in your captivity, to be none else than Kalaratri (the goddess presiding over and responsible for dissolution), who can destroy the entire Lanka."

---

Sage Valmiki described at different occasions almost all Vedic Pantheon in Srimad Ramayana.  However, I did not come across KAALARATRI - काल रात्री.

Can anybody explain who this KAALARATRI - काल रात्री is?

Comment: Kaalratri is the seventh form of Nav Durga. More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaalratri)

Comment: @Aby:  I know this Kaalaratri, a form of Durga.  However, as far as I know,  In Srimad Ramayana period, no female deity, except Gayatri, was worshipped.  In this background, I asked this question.  Even Gayatri was mentioned in Aranya Kanda only.

Comment: Devi Uma was worshipped. And Nav Durga is said to be the 9 forms of Devi Uma/Parvati. Btw, Ganga was also worshipped as a goddess.

Comment: @Aby: Please do not go by Puranas.  Puranas were written to eulogise respective deities.  Vishnu purana - vishnu;;;Shiva purana - Shiva ;;;; devi bhagavatam: Durga.  Durga was worshiped in Ramayana period.  Please check.

Comment: I was telling from Valmiki Ramayana only. There are stories in Balakanda regarding Birth of Lord Kartikeya, there Devi Uma was shown as goddess.  Similarly, there is the episode of bringing Ganga on earth.

Comment: न लोका धारयिष्यन्ति तव तेजः सुरोत्तम |
ब्राह्मेण तपसा युक्तो देव्या सह तपः चर || १-३६-१०
त्रैलोक्य हित काम अर्थम् तेजः तेजसि धारय |
रक्ष सर्वान् इमान् लोकान् न अलोकम् कर्तुम् अर्हसि || १-३६-११ Here Devas are praying to Lord Shiva and 'देव्या' refers to Devi Uma

Comment: The meaning of the text is :  'Worlds cannot capably bear your offspring born out of your effulgence, oh, Supreme-God, hence you may practice yogic asceticism along with your consort Goddess Uma in unison with Vedic postulates of Yoga, rather than progeniture, and desiring the welfare of the three worlds you may please retain your refulgent seed within your own radiance, thus protect this universe, since it will not be apt of you to render it devoid of worlds with the efflux of the unmanageable potence of yours .' So said gods to Shiva. [1-36-10, 11]

Comment: Some scholars think about this Shiva and Uma and the birth of Kaartikeya episodes as an insertion for 2 reasons.  (1) It is not style of Sage Valmiki to describe too much which is not relevant to the Main story.  In the same analogy they say even Sage Vishwamitra's episodes (consisting of some 15 Sargas, I think, as insertion. (2) Kaartikeya was not the son of Shiva.  He was referred to as AGNIBHUH - son of Agni

Comment: @Aby: Even Mahabharata indicates that Kaartikeya was in fact the son of AGNI.  Further, it also tell the story of Kaartikeya killing the great demon Mahisha, who was latter described in Puranas as killed by Devi.

Comment: (1/2)1. Kartikeya is most certainly the son of Shiva. Agni merely carried Shiva 's Tejas. 2. If one believes they are insertions, no counter argument shall be sufficient. 3. Subrahmanya' s story is narrated both in the ramayana and mahabharata as a precursor to slaying demons and enemies 4. It is incorrect to state that valmiki would not go into detail that are not related to the main story. to wit, He describes the seasons at length in the poetic tradition.

Comment: (2/2)5. Kalaratri did not come into being at a later time. She existed from time immemorial . she is the same as kali.The dasamahavidyas revealed themselves to Shiva well before ramayana. According to Wikipedia, kali finds mention in mandukya upanishad. 6.puranas definitely expound on the vedas. They are not mere poetic flights of fancy of a devotee

Comment: @Aby "However, as far as I know, In Srimad Ramayana period, no female deity, except Gayatri, was worshipped."  What are you talking about? There are lots of goddesses described in the Vedas.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan: please quote the deities worshipped in vedic era

Comment: It is belived that Goddess Parvati had cursed Ravana's ancestor(Pulastya or Vishrawa) that She will one day burn the whole golden Lanka down.